# Split a 2d array typescript html with slice

Tags: html, typescript, matrix, multidimensional-array, slice

I'm trying to split the columns of a matrix in my page view with the `slice`. If I `slice:0:1`, the page shows me only the first column. But I don't understand why if I try to select the `slice:1:2` it doesn't show me only the second column, but still only the first column. Same for the `2:3`, `3:4`, etc.

```html
<div class="container">    
    <tr *ngFor="let row of matrix; index as r">
        <td *ngFor="let column of row|slice:0:1; index as c">
            
            <select [(ngModel)]="object[r][c]">
            {{r}}{{c}}
            </select>
        
        </td>
    </tr>
</div>
```

```
ngOnInit() {
    for (let r = 0; r < 6; r++) {
      this.normalizedMatrix.push([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
      this.matrix[r] = []
      this.object[r] = {}
      this.object[r][r] = 1
      for (let c = 0; c < 6; c++) {
        if (r == c) {
          this.matrix[r].push(1)
          this.object[r][c] = 1
        }
        if (r > c) {
          this.matrix[r].push(1 / 9)
          this.object[r][c] = 1 / 9
        }
        else if (r < c) {
          this.matrix[r].push(9)
          this.object[r][c] = 9
        }
      }
    }
    this.onSelectChange(0, 0)
  }
```

Comment: What does slice return? Sounds like it might be returning the column that is removed? Can you show us an example of `matrix` value(s)?

Comment: @joshvito I used slice not to delete the column but because I want a list view of the matrix values. It seemed like the best solution. Do you think there is a better way to view the html of a listed matrix?

Comment: This may be working, have you tried rendering out a value from the `column` variable?
The index `c` may change when the `slice` pipe's value changes.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a working example of the pipe.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uebv3b?file=src/app/app.component.html)
Seems like maybe you are just looking at the column index values, which will change with the pipe values. This is because the slice pipe acts like the js slice in that it "Creates a new Array or String containing a subset (slice) of the elements." [ng docs](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe)

```
//component.html
<div class="container">
    <tr *ngFor="let row of matrix; index as r">
        <td *ngFor="let column of row|slice:1:2; index as c">

            <p>R: {{r}} C: {{c}} - {{column}}</p>>

        </td>
    </tr>
</div>


//component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  matrix = [
    ['row 1 col 1', 'row 1 col 2'],
    ['row 2 col 1', 'row 2 col 2'],
    ['row 3 col 1', 'row 3 col 2']
  ];
}
```

Comment: ah ok, I understand. But now I have a problem. I need the variable `c` to pre-insert data from .ts . I can't replace it with columns. I add the .ts in the main question

Comment: I wouldn't write your component in a way where you depend on the index in the view, as it is not reliable. As you can see.